# When to use short,byte and hex primitive types in program?

Tags: java, hex, byte, primitive-types, short

**short can accommodate the value max 16 bit**

But i have not seen anybody using shor primituve take. Should it not be encourage when i am sure value will fit
with in 32 bit. For example :- i generally see constant as int for value of 1 also. Is it right?

**byte**

I am not sure what kind of scenario i may be requires to use byte primitive data type like byte var1 =3;

Similarly not sure what are the valid scenario wher developer has to go for hexadecimal values liken

```
   public final static int    var2   = 0x001D;
```

Comment: Given the choice, use an `int`. If you don't know why you would use a `byte`, then simply do not use it and you're fine.

Comment: "Hex" is not a primitive type.  It's just a different way of specifying a number.  The choice of whether to use a hex, decimal, or other literal depends solely on what will be most understandable to someone reading a program.  The program **never** "has" to use a hexadecimal value.

Comment: Suppose you have a long journey going by your car, one car holds `100 Liter` of petrol, and other `50`. What car you will choose?
You probably choose the first one, the variables are same, choose the one that holds lot of data, as you must consider the worst case always.

Comment: You know, you're dealing with computer with large memories, maybe when you face a small devices, you should use byte and other small primitive data types.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Does int var1 =15 or byte var2 = 15 have any difference in terms of memory consumption? I mean will var1 will take more memory than var 2 ?

Comment: A `byte` var will take as much memory as an `int` var. The only place where you can actually save memory are arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "never". 
The longer answer is *almost* never. 
Primitives that can hold int values but are smaller than `int` are invented to save memory. This reason is irrelevant for most applications. Memory usage optimization (almost) passed away since computers became very strong and memory very cheap.

Sometimes it is convenient to use `byte` type. However due to java does not have `unsigned` modifier (like C) byte can be confusing: you values greater than 127 become negative. Even method `read()` declared in InputStream returns `int` instead of `byte`.

Sometimes however memory usage optimization becomes relevant again. For example in case of "big data" near real time applications that have to operate with huge in-memory caches and store on disk terabytes of data.

Comment: Does int var1 =15 or byte var2 = 15 have any difference in terms of memory consumption? I mean will var1 will take more memory than var 2 ?

Comment: Yes, `var1` occupies 4 bytes while `var2` only 1  byte.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

usually short / byte is used when saving memory is crucial